# Is there a method to search predicate for a filter method?

Tags: kotlin

im trying to implement a search bar in an app, for example:

```kotlin
val searchOne = "Chocolate"
listOf("Caramel", "Chocolate", "White Chocolate").filter { /* predicate */ }
```

And its result that matches is

```kotlin
listOf("Chocolate", "White Chocolate")
```

I tried use a filter but i dont know what predicate should i use

Answer (score 0):

`Stream.filter()` processes each string in your list. So it receives a string, and you have to determine if "Chocolate" is contained in that string. `String.contains()` would be what you want to use. To cover all possible combinations of upper and lower case, convert your constant `searchOne` to lower case and do the same for the value received by `filter`.

`filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().contains(searchOne))` (Java).

`filter{ it.contains(searchOne, true) }` (Kotlin)